# Set of indices corresponding to a set of elements in a list python3

Tags: python, list, igraph, vertex

I have referred to [this post for finding the index(ices) corresponding to a single named element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-pythonhttps://) in a list, but have not been able to find an answer to my query among the answers there/documentation.

Specifically: is there a more efficient way than just iterating the method in the link above, for finding the indices corresponding to a set of elements?

Say I have the list

```
mybiglist=['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno']
```

and I want the indices corresponding to `'abc','jkl'`

I could do:

```
mytargetlist=['abc','jkl']
for string in mytargetlist:
    print(mybiglist.index('%s' %string))
```

But it feels like there should be a more efficient way than a loop?

In case the context makes a difference, I am trying to find the indices corresponding to certain vertices in a graph, so that I can use induce_subgraph to create a subgraph containing these vertices. Unfortunately I only know the name labels that I want, and which are attributed to the vertices, and the arguments of induce_subraph are: induce_subgraph(graph, vertex set)

Comment: note: `('%s' % string)` is equivalent to just `string`

Comment: Just curious, why do you do `index('%s' %string)` but not `index(string)`?

Comment: It seems you want to optimize a graph algorithm. Maybe you could show the used data structure for a graph. With a better context, a better answer could be provided.

Comment: @QuangHoang For some bizarre reason my code wasn't working with just (string), and I've ben working on it for a week solid so writing it this way has just stuck. Soon as I figure out that bug, I'll polish the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it once through your big list with a comprehension.

```
mybiglist=['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno']
mytargetlist=['abc','jkl']

[i for i, v in enumerate(mybiglist) if v in mytargetlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is kind of simple, maybe could be simplified more with list comprehensions (that's just syntactic sugar...):

```py
mybiglist = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']
mytargetlist = ['abc', 'jkl']
print([mybiglist.index(target) for target in mytargetlist])
```

if you want an overkill solution you can use `numpy` with `isin` and `where` to get the indices without iterating over it yourself:

```py
import numpy as np

mybiglist = np.array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'], dtype=str)
mytargetlist = ['abc', 'jkl']

print(*np.where(np.isin(mybiglist, mytargetlist)))
```

but that seems a little ridiculous :P

Answer (score 0):

`mybiglist.index(string)` has complexity `O(n)`, so basically you do a double for loop on `mybiglist` and `mytargetlist`. You could improve by `enumerate`:

```
indices = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(mybiglist)}
```

and you can access the indices later, i.e. `indices['abc']`.

Answer (score 0):

This will split your target list in chunks and launch separate threads. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html):

```
import concurrent.futures

mybiglist=['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno']
mytargetlist=['abc','jkl']

def get_index(x):
    return mybiglist.index(x)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_index, mytargetlist)

print(list(results))
```